# Error Unit testing Angular 8 / Jasmine / Karma : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to unit test my angular app and sometimes this error below occurs in the Karma window. I can't find where it could come from since it happens about 1/5 times on reloading. It happens when in watch mode. Any clue?

```
zone.js:202 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
      at Array.<anonymous> (VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:110)
      at VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:102
      at d (VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:103)
      at q (VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:106)
      at VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:107
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.w [as prepareStackTrace] (VM2578 browser-source-map-support.js:107)
      at VM2580 jasmine.js:897
      at onerror (VM2580 jasmine.js:3199)
```

Most of the time, after reloading the karma window once, the test sets run again and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the option `ng test --source-map=false` prevents the error from happening, but isnt a permanent solution since it obviously just disables source maps and makes stack traces useless.

Using this option in ci prevents the tests from failing though.

Answer (score -3):

Ran into this issue myself, managed to resolve it by importing the routing module in the specific spec file that was throwing the error.